# Finding and listing all subfolders but nothing else

Tags: shell, applescript

I am trying to make a looping script that will take a parent folder and find all the sub folders. This way I can take them one at a time and run a second script on them.

This would work if I was looking for text files. I want to try to use it for find just folders but don't know how to and can't find anything in that direction.

```
-- Search for Subfolder
set ParentPath to choose folder
set allFiles to (do shell script "find " & quoted form of POSIX path of ParentPath & " -iname \"*.eps\""))


-- Process files
repeat with nFile in allFiles
    my runScript(nFile)
end repeat
```

In theory it would be this.

```
-- Search for Subfolder
set ParentPath to choose folder
set allFiles to all folders inside ParentPath


-- Process files
repeat with nFile in allFiles
    my runScript(nFile)
end repeat
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this works perfectly.

```
set ParentPath to (choose folder) as string
set FolderList to {}
tell application "System Events"
    set ItemList to disk items of folder ParentPath
    repeat with CurrentItem in ItemList
        if (class of CurrentItem) = folder then
            set end of FolderList to ((path of CurrentItem) as alias)
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

With bash, you'd say:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
# the trailing slash below restricts matches to directories.
for dir in **/; do
    some command with "$dir"
done
```

This recursively finds all directories under the current directory. If you're only looking for subdirectories of the current dir: `for dir in */`

Answer (score 0):

```
find <dirname> -type d > subdirlist
```

You don't need to specify depth levels for find, either; it will keep going down to the end.  You actually only specify a max depth if you don't want it to go too far.

You can use a find loop as the basis for your processing script, as well.  As one example:-

```
find *.mp3 d.mp3 -type f | while read mp3s
do 
echo $mp3s
<more commands>
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try below:

```
find ./ -type d
```

Comment: I am writing this in applescript. How would this be formated into a do shell script?

Comment: @Tim Joe So you mean you want to implement this by applescript?

Comment: correct. Not over formillar with it but I know it will be a do shell script("find" ./ -type d)

Comment: @Tim Joe Sorry I have no idea with applescript, I work on linux but never MAC OS. But I think it's really intresting.